# Role switch of special characters in bash

Tags: bash, shell, regular-expression, wildcards

On what basis does the role of asterisk keep changing?

```
CASE 1: 
var1=abcd-1234-defg 
echo ${var1#*-*}        # RESULT: 1234-defg

CASE 2: 
stringZ=abcABC123ABCabc 
echo `expr match "$stringZ" '\(abc[A-Z]*.2\)'`  # RESULT: abcABC12
```

When and how is the role of asterisk decided?

```
CASE 3:
path_name="/home/bozo/ideas/thoughts.for.today"
echo ${path_name##/*/}  # RESULT : thoughts.for.today
```

In this case I mistook `/` to be playing the role of escape character here, i.e., trying to escape the basic characteristic of `*`. Well, I was wrong. So how are the roles of these special characters decided and by whom?

```
CASE 4: 
var1=abcd--1234-defg 
echo ${var1#*-*}        # RESULT: -1234-defg  & i was expecting 1234-defg
```

The CASE 4 is similar to CASE 1, but with a difference as can be seen `abcd--`, and I was expecting `1234-defg`, but the result turned out to be the same as in case 1.

This is how I interpreted `*-*` in CASE 4:

> The shell would look for everything from the start of the var1 till it finds - OR -- OR ---

Why is my interpretation in the context of CASE 4 incorrect?

Comment: More generally, see [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Answer (score 3):

That's because `*` had different meaning in your tests.

In *case 1*, *case 3* and *case 4*, it's use as a [pattern matching](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13). While in *case 2*, it's a [regular expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_03) metacharacter (or quantifier or [Kleene star](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star)).

In pattern matching, `*` character will match any string, include null string, `a*` will match any string start with `a`, example `a`, `aa`, `ab`, but not `b`

In regular expression, `*` quantifier match zero or more occurrences of preceding token, `a*` will match zero or more `a` sequences, example `''`, `a`, `aa`, `aaa`, `ab`, `b`.

With these in mind, your *case 4* will be interpreted as *match any string contain `-`*, because it was used as a pattern matching, your explain in question is used as a regular expression.

So `abcd--1234-defg`, the shortest sub string match `*-*` is `abcd-`, and the longest match is the whole string. Since when you use the form `${var1#*-*}`, which is a [Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) to remove the shortest prefix in `$var1` match `*-*`, you got `-1234-defg`, because the shortest prefix matched is `abcd-`.

Comment: the quantifier version is often called a *Kleene star* after its inventor, [Stephen Kleene](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Cole_Kleene).

Comment: @mikeserv: Thanks for the information. I used it too many times without knowning its origin.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things to understand:

1. In a glob, `*` matches **zero or more** of any character
2. The form `${var1#*-*}` removes the **shortest** match.

Thus, `${var1#*-*}` will only remove up to the first dash because that is the *shortest* match.

For completeness, note `${var1##*-*}` would remove the longest match.

#### Examples

In each case below, the *shortest* matching prefix is removed:

```
$ var1=abcd-1234-defg 
$ echo ${var1#*}
abcd-1234-defg
$ echo ${var1#*-}
1234-defg
$ echo ${var1#*-*}
1234-defg
$ echo ${var1#*-*-}
defg
$ echo ${var1#*-*-*}
defg
```

Contrast the above with the `##` case which removes the *longest* matching prefix:

```
$ echo ${var1##*-}
defg
$ echo ${var1##*-*}

$
```

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> ```
> ${parameter#word}
> ${parameter##word}
> ```
>
> Remove matching prefix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the
>   pattern matches the beginning of the  value  of  parameter, then  the 
>   result  of  the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the
>   **shortest matching pattern** (the `#` case) or the longest matching
>   pattern (the `##` case) deleted.  If parameter is @ or *, the
>   pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in
>   turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter is an
>   array variable subscripted with @ or *, the pattern removal operation
>   is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is
>   the resultant list.  [Emphasis added.]